# Using different icon for different flavor dimension

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I have created two flavors and two dimensions for an Android application. The flavors are free and premium and the dimensions are default and withExtras. What I want to have is the following flavors:

```
freeDefault
|---freeWithExtras

premiumDefault
|---premiumWithExtras
```

The withExtras dimensions should be based on the default flavors but add some more functionality. I would also like to have a different icon for the freeWithExtras version. I have created a different icon and placed it in the src/withExtras/res/drawable folder. The other (default) icon is in the src/free/res/drawable folder. When I run the freeWithExtras dimension, the icon being used is that from the free/res/drawable folder. How can I make the above dimension use the image that is placed in its res folder? Is there something wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your flavor / dimension setup looks like this:

```
flavorDimensions "mode", "extras"
...
productFlavors {
    free {
      dimension "mode"
    }

    premium {
      dimension "mode"
    }

    default {
      dimension "extras"
    }

    withExtras {
      dimension "extras"
    }
}
```

You should be able to create a source folder for your specific build variant `freeWithExtras` which combines two flavors. Then you can and place your icon into `src/freeWithExtras/res`. [The order you specify your `flavorDimensions` controls the order in which the flavors are concatenated](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions) to build the folder / build variant name.